# Pending Intent stops working after few hours

Tags: android-pendingintent

I am presently trying to wake my application when the user starts or stops walking. Here's the code. I have used pending intent so that it would trigger even when my application is killed.

The code works and the pending intent sends the event to broadcast receiver. However, after a few hours, it stops working.

I have read pending intent is stored in the RAM. Does OS clear these pending events occassionaly to save memory? If then how do I ensure my pending intent works all the time?

```
public void subscribe(Context context){
            List<ActivityTransition> transitions = new ArrayList<>();

            transitions.add(
                    new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
                            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                            .build());

            transitions.add(
                    new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                            .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
                            .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                            .build());

            ActivityTransitionRequest request = new ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TransitionsReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction(TransitionsReceiver.TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION);

            pendingIntent = pendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            Task<Void> task =
                    ActivityRecognition.getClient(context)
                            .requestActivityTransitionUpdates(request, pendingIntent);

            task.addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                            Log.i("Shield", "Transitions Api was successfully registered.");
                        }
                    });
            task.addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Shield", "Transitions Api could not be registered: " + e);
                        }
                    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ROM you have installed in your phone. Many have battery saver profiles that kill your app and the processes they left, like your intent.

This website has the instructions to avoid this: https://dontkillmyapp.com/